# Swift Mailer stops script on error

Tags: php, lamp, swiftmailer

I've been using Swift Mailer for my LAMP applications, but I've discovered that it will stop the script if it encounters an error, instead of returning an error code.

Is there a way to catch this? If not, can anyone recommend an alternative mail library?

Comment: A start would be telling us what error you're getting.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Swift throws exceptions so you should catch these.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. The script just stops.

I tried setting up a "try" and "catch", but it wasn't getting anything. I'll try again.